# How to use a loop to capitalize first occurring lowercase letter of string Java

Tags: java

Prompt: Use a loop to find the first occurring lowercase letter in the input string.
Then capitalize ONLY the lowercase letter you found, and then re-combine it with the rest of the string.

I'm so confused because one I don't know the exact number of indexes because it varies and two how can I capitalize only the first occurring lowercase. For example inputs are like BYus where I'm only supposed to capitalize the u. I have

```
public class PasswordImprover {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        userInput = sc.next();
        int userLowerCase = userInput.indexOf(".*[a-z].*");

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(userInput.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.print(userInput.toUpperCase().charAt(i));

            } else if (!userInput.contains(".*[a-z].*")) {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

but this just outputs everything in uppercase. Please help.

Comment: Curious about your choice of regex. Why is it there? You can already check for lowercase strings using String functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of that regex and just use a simple loop and a flag to indicate that you have process the first LC char

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput= sc.next();
boolean done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
   if (!done && Character.isLowerCase(userInput.charAt(i))) {
      System.out.print(userInput.toUpperCase().charAt(i));
      done = true;
  }
  else  {
      System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i));
  }
      
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was great! I don't know why adding the boolean done piece made it work but it did.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm so confused because one I don't know the exact number of indexes because it varies

Yes, that would the reason for the loop

> how can I capitalize only the first occurring lowercase

Well, there's a few ways you might do it.  `String#substring` might be starting point, for example...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "BYus";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);

        for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(sb.charAt(index))) {
                test = test.substring(0, index) + Character.toUpperCase(test.charAt(index)) + test.substring(index + 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

or, if you want to be a little more efficient, you could use a `StringBuilder`, for example...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "BYus";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);

        for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(sb.charAt(index))) {
                sb.replace(index, index + 1, Character.toString(test.charAt(index)).toUpperCase());
                break;
            }
        }
        test = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

You could also convert the `String` to a character array and simply replace the first lower cased character in it and build a new `String` at the end, for example...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "BYus";
        char[] characters = test.toCharArray();

        for (int index = 0; index < characters.length; index++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(characters[index])) {
                characters[index] = Character.toUpperCase(test.charAt(index));
                break;
            }
        }

        test = new String(characters);

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

So, you know, options

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the input as an array of `char`s:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string ");
        char[] userInput = sc.next().toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(userInput[i])) {
                userInput[i] = Character.toUpperCase(userInput[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(userInput));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for regex.

```java
String str = "BYus";
str = str.replaceFirst("([^a-z]*.).*", "$1").toUpperCase() + str.replaceFirst("[^a-z]*.(.*)", "$1");
System.out.println(str); //BYUs
```